# Исключение System.InvalidCastException в потоке (Task)

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Добрый день.

Имеется такая конструкция необходимая для ожидания полной загрузки страницы в компоненте webbrowser:

```
        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

В главном потоке работает отлично, но вот при выполнении в Task с использованием async await выдает исключение System.InvalidCastException на эту строку:

```
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего подобное происходит и как это возможно обойти?

Спасибо.

Comment: Выложите весь стек исключения, пожалуйста.
Application.DoEvents() поднимать в Task'е не стоит, нечего ему там делать.

Comment: Никаких данных кроме этих нет: 

Исключение:Вызвано: "Заданное приведение является недопустимым." (System.InvalidCastException)
Возникло System.InvalidCastException: "Заданное приведение является недопустимым."
Time: 11.05.2013 21:11:47
Поток:<Без имени>[2140]

А как тогда грамотно дождаться полной загрузки страницы в webbrowser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по тому, что подсказывает интернет, проблема в самом свойстве ReadyState. Оно не потокобезопасно, так что рекомендуется использовать Invoke.

Пример, вполне рабочий.

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");
        await Wait();
    }

    private Task Wait()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while ((WebBrowserReadyState)webBrowser1.Invoke(new Func<WebBrowserReadyState>(() => webBrowser1.ReadyState)) != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                await Task.Delay(100);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю, помогло.

Comment: Если не сложно подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью Invoke присвоить значение:  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("phone").InnerText = "текст";

Comment: Вы не совсем понимаете принцип работы метода Invoke. В данный метод передаётся делегат, который просто выполняется в том же потоке, в котором был создан элемент управления. В своём примере я передал туда делегат Func<WebBrowserReadyState>. Если теперь не требуется возращение результата, то получится примерно так:
  
    webBrowser1.Invoke(new Action(() => webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("phone").InnerText = "текст"));

Вот только не надо забывать, что если внутри делегата будет "долгоиграющий код", то подвесите Вы основной поток.

Comment: Благодарю за пример и разъяснение.

Comment: Еще один вопрос на тему webbrowser в потоке (чтобы не висла форма) - на ваш взгляд какое решение для этого следует использовать? А то кто-то пишет что webbrowser в потоках нельзя использовать (только в главном потоке) т.к. webbrowser - компонент и т.д.

Comment: Все элементы управления можно использовать только в том потоке, в котором они были созданы. Microsoft гарантирует безопасность в основном для статичных методов. Зависит все от задачи на самом деле, я бы лично вообще постарался бы не использовать webbrowser как таковой. Работать с DOM можно и просто загрузив страницу, а webbrowser уже использовал бы для отображения результата изменений.