# c#, формы, многопоточность, webbrowser

Tags: c#, многопоточность, forms

Есть стороннее приложение и форма, которую он вызывает.
При нажатии нужной клавиши стороннее приложение вызывает следующий метод формы

```
{
    Thread ThA2 = new Thread(() =>
    {
       try
       {
          this.webBrowser1.Document.Write("cat");
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
    });
    ThA2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    ThA2.Start();
}
```

Код вызывает ошибку **Заданное приведение является недопустимым**. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Исключение System.InvalidCastException в потоке (Task)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/218756/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-system-invalidcastexception-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-task)

Answer (score 0):

Одно из золотых правил: не трогать свойства и методы контрола из потока, отличного от того, в котором создан это контрол (если только явно не указано, что этот метод/свойство можно вызывать/менять из другого потока).

Для изменения состояния контрола из "чужого" потока необходимо передать вызов в поток интерфейса через `Invoke` или `BeginInvoke`.

В приведенном случае можно поступить так:

```
this.webBrowser1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { this.webBrowser1.Document.Write("cat"); });
```